# How to have a MySQL table column with a calculated value

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

My question is easiest to explain using an example...

I have the following two tables - planes and seats:

```
planes
 plane_ID     LONGINT - Index
 model        CHAR(20)
 seat_count   INT - Calculated (Count of rows in seats where plane_ID matches)
 filled_seats INT - Calculated (Count of rows in seats where plane_ID matches and reserved = True)

seats
 plane_ID  LONGINT
 reserved  bool
```

What I would like to happen, is when I query the planes table, I would like to get calculated values for the "seats" column and the "filled_seats" column.

I simply want to say "SELECT seat_count FROM planes WHERE model='Boeing 787'" to find out how many records there are in the seats table for a Boeing 787. What I expect is a single row returned, with a single column containing the number of seats for a Boeing 787.

This could be done with a more complicated select statement, but I want to use calculated columns instead.

I know that this can be done, but I don't know how, nor do I know what it's called, so I'm having difficulty finding any information online.

I'm using MySQL v 8.0.19 on Linux

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: MySQL version 8.0.19

Comment: @Calab Could you please add your expected output format? it will help.

Comment: You wouldn't normally store derived data

Comment: @Strawberry: "normally"–I see what you did there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`Generated columns`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html), but you can't do what you want with them as the expressions can only contain "Literals, deterministic built-in functions, and operators" and specifically: "Subqueries are not permitted.".

You can achieve what you want with a `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW plane_seats AS
SELECT p.plane_ID, p.model, 
       COUNT(s.reserved) AS seat_count,
       SUM(s.reserved) AS filled_seats
FROM planes p
JOIN seats s ON s.plane_ID = p.plane_ID
GROUP BY p.plane_ID, p.model
```

You can then use your query on the `VIEW`:

```
SELECT seat_count 
FROM plane_seats
WHERE model = 'Boeing 787'
```

Comment: Great answer. I didn't realize you could sum booleans! You need a `group by p.plane_id`.

Comment: @Schwern MySQL treats booleans as either 1 (true) or 0 (false) in a numeric context. It definitely makes writing these queries a lot easier than the old `CASE WHEN... ` or `IF...` expression

Comment: Do you need to group by model? It should be redundant with the plane_id.

Comment: @Schwern it depends on whether `plane_ID` is a primary key or not. If it's not, then with the default `only_full_group_by` mode in MySQL 8 then you need to include the other columns too. From the question it's not clear if `plane_ID` is a primary key so I decided to err on the safe side.